# How can I open Drawer Layout moving all the view and not just slide over?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

How can I open Drawer Layout moving all the view and not just slide over?

The idea would be to make the menu like Facebook and not like GMail, for example. I've been looking for information and haven't found anything. It can be done? It's possible with Drawer Layout? How?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Since this works against Google's style guide (https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html), I doubt that `DrawerLayout` will support this. Other third-party navigation drawers may have this option, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you **dont want to use third-party libraries**, you can implement it yourself just overriding the onDrawerSlide from the ActionBarDrawerToggle. There you can translate your framelayout view based on the opening % of your drawer.

Example with code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>    

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here, override onDrawerSlide:

```
public class ConfigurerActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private FrameLayout frame;
    private float lastTranslate = 0.0f;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.acc_drawer_open, R.string.acc_drawer_close) 
        {            
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
            {
                float moveFactor = (mDrawerList.getWidth() * slideOffset);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
                {
                    frame.setTranslationX(moveFactor);
                }
                else
                {
                    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(lastTranslate, moveFactor, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                    anim.setDuration(0);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                    frame.startAnimation(anim);

                    lastTranslate = moveFactor;
                }
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // ... more of your code
    }
}
```

Since setTranslationX is not available in pre-honeycomb android versions, i managed it using TranslateAnimation for lower version devices.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

The thing you are using is navigation drawer but you have to use

### menu drawer##

for the menu like facebook and gmail.

i have implemented it and this link will help you to do so.

Here's [a link](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-sliding-menu-navigation-drawer.html/)!

this will tell you all the steps for making menu drawer.

dont forget to **Vote Up** the answer if it is helfull.

thanks.